# Offering a human translation for cryptic google-translated questions

Tags: discussion, support, editing, languages

If there is a question where the text was clearly google translated with a cryptic result, is it OK to ask the author to provide the text in the original language so that I can edit his/her question and translate it into proper English?

Comment: I don't see why not, as long as you actually edit it __;-)__.

Comment: Speaking of edits, very often the original message can be found in the edit history

Answer (score 4):

Of course; asking the author to clarify the question (in a way that is helpful) is always fine.

You can also post a comment in their native language. If you want to be extra nice, post the comment in english and whatever language it is, so the other readers can figure out what's going on.